A PMOS doesn't turn on/off properly
I'm designing a ON/OFF circuit for fans using NMOS and PMOS.
To adhere maximum rating of a PMOS (AONR21305C) which VG is 20V.
Therefore, I added a divider (R8). After adding it a PMOS doesn't turn on/off properly.
What did I miss?
Here is a working circuit and waveforms (Maximum rating ignored).
Red, blue, green refer input, VG and output, repectively.


Here is another circuits and waveforms which a divider added.



Why not use the Nch FET to drive the fan low-side?

Your divider should reduce 24 volts to something like 12V, like this:
EDIT As OP has noted, gate-to-source voltage magnitude must be kept below 20V. Since the voltage at the PMOS source pin is +24V, gate voltage must not reach ground - gate drive must be attenuated by at least 4V. If attenuated too much, the PMOS won't act as a clean switch.
The circuit described here uses two equal-value resistors (1K) as a voltage divider that attenuates 24V down to 12V. When the NMOS pulls its drain down to ground, the PMOS's gate pulls down to +12V, so that the PMOS gate-to-source voltage difference is -12V. That's enough to adequately switch the PMOS, yet leaves 8V of headroom so that gate-to-source voltage never exceeds the spec-sheet -20V limit.
When the NMOS is off, the PMOS gate is pulled-up to +24V by R2, so that gate-to-source voltage is zero...the PMOS becomes an open-circuit.

Thanks for your guide but simulation results still indicate 24V at VG

Gate-to-source of that PMOS never exceeds 12V (within specs).

@YWS A potential of $V_G=+24V$ is the state where M5 is off. Remember that it is the potential difference $V_{GS}=V_G-V_S$ that determines state. When $V_G=+24V$, then $V_{GS}=V_G-V_S=(+24V)-(+24V)=0V$, and MOSFET M5 is off.

Dear Glen and Simon, Those help me a lot, I hope you have a good day.
